Finding a basis for a linear transformation where the basis is not given
What would be the right way to approach the following question?

Consider the linear transformation $\theta: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\theta(x) = Ax$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ -3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Find an ordered basis $\underline{b} = (b_1,b_2)$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the matrix representation of $\theta$ with respect to $\underline{b}$ is $[\theta]_{\underline{b,b}} = \begin{bmatrix}-21 & 103 \\ -5 & 24\end{bmatrix}$.
Hint: $[\theta]_{\underline{e,e}} = A$ where $\underline{e}$ is the standard basis.

You should leave your approach/thoughts on this.

For any matrix representation, $[T]_{a,a}$, we have: $$[T]_{b,b} = Q^{-1} \cdot [T]_{a,a} \cdot Q
$$
where $ Q $ is the change of basis matrix (the matrix that maps each basis vector of $ b $ to each basis vector in $ a $). In particular, to your question $ Qe_1 = b_1 $ and $ Qe_2 = b_2 $, therefore $ Q $ just has $ b_1 $ and $ b_2 $ as its columns. This information should be plenty for you to create a system of equations and solve it that way.
